# Automatically update dictionary values?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a list like this

```
df = ['20180001\tJane\t84\t73\n', '20180002\tLee\t92\t89\n', '20180007\tSteve\t57\t62\n',
      '20180009\tDonald\t81\t84\n', '20180011\tLuke\t58\t68\n']
```

and I put it in to the dictionary with this code:

```
temp_dict = {}
for i in range(len(df)):
    temp_dict[df[i].split("\t")[0]] = df[i].split("\t")[1:4]

for i in [*temp_dict]:
    temp_dict[i][1] = int(temp_dict[i][1]) # (A)
    temp_dict[i][2] = int(temp_dict[i][2].strip("\n")) # (B)
    temp_dict[i].append((temp_dict[i][1] + temp_dict[i][2])/2) #average for A and B
    temp_dict[i].append(grade((temp_dict[i][1] + temp_dict[i][2])/2)) #return average
                                                                      #as letter grade

def grade(num):
    if  num>= 90:
        return  'A'
    if num >= 80:
        return  'B'
    if num >= 70:
        return  'C'
    if num >= 60:
        return  'D'
    else:
        return  'F' #grade function
```

So temp_list comes like this:

```
{'20180001': ['Jane', 84, 73, 78.5, 'C'],
 '20180002': ['Lee', 100, 89, 90.5, 'A'],
 '20180007': ['Steve', 100, 62, 59.5, 'F'],
 '20180009': ['Donald', 81, 84, 82.5, 'B'],
 '20180011': ['Luke', 58, 68, 63.0, 'D']}
```

But everytime I update one of `A` or `B`, average and letter grade are not change. Is there anyway that average and letter grade automatically change when I update `A` or `B`?

Comment: How are you now updating the `A` or `B` of a dictionary entry?

Answer (score 0):

You can define a function to update grades which automatically recalculates the overall (average) grade and associated letter grade:

```
def grade(num):
    if  num>= 90:
        return  'A'
    if num >= 80:
        return  'B'
    if num >= 70:
        return  'C'
    if num >= 60:
        return  'D'
    else:
        return  'F' #grade function

def updateGrade(data, i, gradeIndex, new_grade):
    #grade index is 1 for first grade, 2 for second grade
    data[i][gradeIndex] = new_grade
    data[i][3] = (data[i][1] + data[i][2])/2 #average for A and B
    data[i][4] = grade(data[i][3]) #return average as letter grade

df = ['20180001\tJane\t84\t73\n', '20180002\tLee\t92\t89\n', '20180007\tSteve\t57\t62\n',
      '20180009\tDonald\t81\t84\n', '20180011\tLuke\t58\t68\n']
temp_dict = {}
for i in range(len(df)):
    temp_dict[df[i].split("\t")[0]] = df[i].split("\t")[1:4]

for i in [*temp_dict]:
    temp_dict[i][1] = int(temp_dict[i][1]) # (A)
    temp_dict[i][2] = int(temp_dict[i][2].strip("\n")) # (B)
    temp_dict[i].append((temp_dict[i][1] + temp_dict[i][2])/2) #average for A and B
    temp_dict[i].append(grade((temp_dict[i][1] + temp_dict[i][2])/2)) #return average
                                                                      #as letter grade
print(temp_dict)
updateGrade(temp_dict, '20180001', 1, 50)
print(temp_dict)
```

Sample output:

```
{'20180001': ['Jane', 84, 73, 78.5, 'C'], '20180002': ['Lee', 92, 89, 90.5, 'A'], '20180007': ['Steve', 57, 62, 59.5, 'F'], '20180009': ['Donald', 81, 84, 82.5, 'B'], '20180011': ['Luke', 58, 68, 63.0, 'D']}
{'20180001': ['Jane', 50, 73, 61.5, 'D'], '20180002': ['Lee', 92, 89, 90.5, 'A'], '20180007': ['Steve', 57, 62, 59.5, 'F'], '20180009': ['Donald', 81, 84, 82.5, 'B'], '20180011': ['Luke', 58, 68, 63.0, 'D']}
```

Answer (score 0):

An object-oriented way to do it would be to derive a dictionary subclass that has a special method that automatically does the calculates whenever a dictionary entry is added or changed — but otherwise behaves like regular Python `dict`.

Here's what I am suggesting:

```
class Grades(dict):
    def __init__(self, df):
        super().__init__()  # Initialize base class.
        for item in df:
            self.set_entry(item)

    def set_entry(self, value):
        key, name, A, B = value.split("\t")
        A, B = map(int, (A, B))
        average = (A + B) / 2
        self[key] = [name, A, B, average, self.grade(average)]

    def grade(self, num):
        if num >= 90:
            return  'A'
        if num >= 80:
            return  'B'
        if num >= 70:
            return  'C'
        if num >= 60:
            return  'D'
        return 'F'


if __name__ == '__main__':
    from pprint import pprint

    df = ['20180001\tJane\t84\t73\n', '20180002\tLee\t92\t89\n',
          '20180007\tSteve\t57\t62\n', '20180009\tDonald\t81\t84\n',
          '20180011\tLuke\t58\t68\n']

    grades = Grades(df)
    print('Before:')
    pprint(grades)
    grades.set_entry('20180001\tJane\t84\t95\n')  # Update Jane's entry.
    print()
    print('After:')
    pprint(grades)
```

Output:

```
Before:
{'20180001': ['Jane', 84, 73, 78.5, 'C'],
 '20180002': ['Lee', 92, 89, 90.5, 'A'],
 '20180007': ['Steve', 57, 62, 59.5, 'F'],
 '20180009': ['Donald', 81, 84, 82.5, 'B'],
 '20180011': ['Luke', 58, 68, 63.0, 'D']}

After:
{'20180001': ['Jane', 84, 95, 89.5, 'B'],
 '20180002': ['Lee', 92, 89, 90.5, 'A'],
 '20180007': ['Steve', 57, 62, 59.5, 'F'],
 '20180009': ['Donald', 81, 84, 82.5, 'B'],
 '20180011': ['Luke', 58, 68, 63.0, 'D']}
```